# Bleichenbacher '06 signature forgery against modified PKCS1 v1.5 format

Tags: rsa, forgery, pkcs1

Bleichenbacher’s  ’06 RSA signature forgery targets incorrect PKCS1 v1.5 implementations where padding checks are omitted and RSA keys with  `e = 3` are used.

As per [the answer to a related question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52893), the attack has the following additional assumption

> … with the assumption that the lsbit of the hash is a 1 (or more generally, that the number of 0’s at the end of the hash is a multiple of 3); this assumption is necessary, because if it is not true, no perfect cube will exist. It turns out if this assumption is true, then a cube will always exist.

Say I modified the `EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5-ENCODE` signature encoding to fix the least significant byte to `0x02`. The full format would be

```
EM = 0x00 || 0x01 || PS' || 0x00 || T || 0x02
```

Where `PS’` consists of `emLen - tLen - 4` bytes with hexadecimal value `0xff`. `T` is structured as in the original encoding format, hence it includes the hash to be signed.

This format violates the assumption detailed above.

Are there practical forgery attacks against signature verification routines based on the format above that do not check the padding `PS'`, but verify that (a) the signature starts with `00 01`, (b) the signature ends with `0x02`, and the length of `EM` is correct (assuming `e = 3`)?

I’m only interested in attacks where the attacker gets to choose the message (hash) to be signed.

Comment: The description of what the verifier checks is likely lacking: if it does not check at least some of the hash part of `T`, then any signature valid for one message is valid for any other message! Please tell the size of `T`, how much of it is the hash of the message, and what in `T` is checked. Independently: in _"the attacker gets to choose the message (hash) to be signed"_, is it assumed the attacker chooses the message, or the adversary chooses the hash value? For a preimage-resistant hash, that's different. Both are possible (e.g. if the hashing is external to a signing device).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the attacker should attempt to find an integer cube of the form $EM+N$ or $EM-N$ where $N$ is the RSA modulus. Note that $N$ is odd so that the LSB of $E+N$ is 1 and there is no prohibition on the number being a cube. The degrees of freedom permitted by the digits of PS will still permit a cube to be found for suitable sizes of emlen and tlen.

Verification will still pass as our cube will be reduced modulo $N$ leaving the same $EM$ to be incorrectly parsed as before.

Comment: Yes. Addition: for the $\mathtt{EM}-N$ attack, which seems to be the best variant, we want to find `PS'` generating an $\mathtt{EM}$ such that $N-\mathtt{EM}=x^3$. Then $N-x$ is a valid signature.